# Mongoose only saves array of object _id value

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to post the messages array to mongoose database, but it only saves the _id property instead the content and sender property too. What am I doing wrong?

Group Schema:

```
var GroupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlenght: 1,
        trim: true
    },
    messages: {
        type: [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Message'}]
    },
    _creator: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true
    }
});
```

Message Schema:

```
var MessageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlenght: 1,
        trim: true
    },
    sender: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
```

POST /rooms route without saving

```
const messages = [];
for (const m of req.body.messages) {
    messages.push(new Message(m));

}

var group = new Group({
    name: req.body.name,
    _creator: req.user._id,
    messages: messages
});
```

[JSON data in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaRAX.png)

[When I run GET I only get back the messages objectID values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SF4cR.png)

Comment: Are you saying that your `GroupSchema` only saves the message ids?

Comment: yes, it's seen on the second picture below

Comment: That is because the `GroupSchema` only saves the reference ids of  `MessageSchema` schema records. And you will find the corresponding `content` and `sender` in `MessageSchema`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. You have a cross-reference between your `GroupSchema` and your `MessageSchema` via:

```
messages: {
    type: [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Message'}]
}
```

What this means is that `GroupSchema/messages` would **only** contain the ObjectIds of the messages cross referenced with your Messages collection.

You need to use [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) to get the actual documents loaded.

> The **ref** option is what tells Mongoose which model to use during
>   population.